# Android: How to use a Onclicklistener in a class file

Tags: java, android, class, onclicklistener

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.lr);
new PINT();
}


}
```

Pint.java

```
public class Pint {

puclic void Pint()
{
}

public void PINT(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case (R.id.rightleft):
        X(0);
        break;
    case (R.id.rightleft):
        X(1);
        break;
    }
}

public void X(int x) {
    if (x == 0) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (x == 1) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

running the code above fails, i want to be able to use an onclicklister from a class file, how would i go about doing this?

all thats in the xml is just two buttons

Comment: Why not defining the OnClickListener in your Activity?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a separate class?

Comment: mostly for readability

Comment: This code doesn't compile, actually.

Comment: @Shlubu if you read what i said, you'd know that, i said 'running the code above fails'

Comment: It doesn't fail: it doesn't execute at all. Try fixing the compile errors one by one, and should one of them sound weird, let us know. The first one is probably "puclic"

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
          super.onCreate(paramBundle);
          setContentView(R.layout.lr);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (view.getId()) {
               case (R.id.rightleft):
                    X(0);
                    break;
               case (R.id.rightleft):
                    X(1);
                    break;
          }
     }

     public void X(int x) {
          (x == 0) 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left",      
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          (x == 1) 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class file must extend one of the View classes for the OnClickListener to work.

Besides that, what is this?(

```
public void X(int x) {
(x == 0) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
(x == 1) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I guess you are missing if statemens:

```
public void X(int x) {
if(x == 0) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
else
if(x == 1) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}
```

Comment: what you are doing is no good for readibility. you only make more code this way.